# How to get user's media through Instagram Api?

Tags: instagram-api

I can see my media using

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=**MY_ACCESS-TOKEN**
```

I want to get user's media, so I use this

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/**ID_USER**/media/recent/?access_token=**MY_ACCESS_TOKEN**
```

I get an error, because his account is private

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"APINotAllowedError","code":400,"error_message":"you cannot view this resource"}}
```

But I follow him, so I should see his media. What should I do ?

Comment: are u in sandbox mode ?

Comment: Its a bug I think, some else also reported the same

Comment: @krisrak Yes. I am in sandbox mode, but I added users and tested on them.

Comment: i tried it too, its a bug

Comment: Any news from this? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following link works for me without any authentication

```
https://www.instagram.com/{username}/media/
```

Answer (score 0):

Before getting the access token, did u include the scope in getting the access code like the call of api below?

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[]&redirect_uri=[]&response_type=code&scope=public_content

You must set the scope of permission to public content in order to access other user's media.

Comment: Yes, I include scopes