# Instagram Media/Feed API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am currently looking at Instagram feed integration in a web app.
The offical APIs are: [Instagram Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/v2.10) and [Instagram Platform API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/).

And then I found one endpoint like `https://www.instagram.com/instagram/media/` on SO, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373886/how-can-i-get-a-users-media-from-instagram-without-authenticating-as-a-user/33783840#33783840) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38049482/1061092), which seems an undocumented (at least I haven't seen it on facebook/instagram document).
It's publicly accessible and you can get a lot of information about the posts including likes and comments.

So my questions are:

- Is the `https://www.instagram.com/{username}/media/` documented some where?
- Is it widely used on the internet?

Comment: In 2020 you can just use: https://www.instafeed.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not official API, it may stop working anytime, not a good idea to use in a App. Other Instagram undocumented APIs have stopped working in the past, its good to use for one-off projects but I would not use it in a app/website.

Comment: You're right, that we shouldn't use an undocumented api. I thought people must have seen this and probably can provide some more details :)

Comment: you can use it, I use it sometimes too, but I dont rely on it or write apps with it.

Comment: may I ask what do you use it for?

Comment: to get image links in bulk

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59526137/my-app-was-rejected-by-instagram-basic-display-api-review-due-to-invalid-reasons

Answer (score 0):

This endpoint has stopped working on November 7 2017. But you can use this other endpoint to get the same results:

```
GET /users/user-id/media/recent
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

Get the most recent media published by a user.
The public_content scope is required if the user is not the owner of the access_token.

REQUIREMENTS
Scope: public_content

PARAMETERS
ACCESS_TOKEN    A valid access token.
MAX_ID  Return media earlier than this max_id.
MIN_ID  Return media later than this min_id.
COUNT   Count of media to return.
```

https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent

Comment: This is now not working as stated here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [small library](https://github.com/webistomin/nanogram.js) on typescript. It doesn't require access token or client id.The library uses RegExp under the hood. You can get your photos like this:

```
import Nanogram from 'nanogram.js';

const instagramParser = new Nanogram();

instagramParser.getMediaByUsername('instagram').then((media) => {
  console.log(media);
 });
```